# Bootstrap form-control class preventing centering of input

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In my two divs I'm using `form-control` and `form-control-lg` and I want the input centered. The problem is the input is aligned left. Only when I take out the `form-control` class will it center (with just `form-control-lg` left in). But obviously this takes away the formatting.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="text-center border border-primary">
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg w-75">
</div>

<br>

<div class="text-center border border-primary">
  <input type="text" class="form-control-lg w-75">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reading on next documentation: [Boostrap 4 - Justify Content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content).

I have found that you have to use **d-flex** in combination with **justify-content-center** for center the items inside a container. Even more, forms have a class for this in replacement for d-flex, it is called **form-inline**. I give you an example with the two options, but I recommend the **option 2** for this case.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<h4 class="text-bold text-primary">Option 1</h4>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center border border-primary">
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg w-75" value="Center using d-flex and justify-content-center"/>
</div>

<br>

<h4 class="text-bold text-primary">Option 2</h4>
<div class="form-inline justify-content-center border border-primary">
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg w-75" value="Center using form-inline and justify-content-center"/>
</div>

<br>

<h4 class="text-bold text-primary">Option 3 (BAD ONE)</h4>
<div class="text-center border border-primary">
  <input type="text" class="form-control-lg w-75" value="Center removing class form-control"/>
</div>
```